# Download from url that generates a file

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api, download, webclient

I need to be able to download a file from url. The url does not link to an actual file instead it generates the file on the server first and then gives a download dialog. Probably returning an mvc FileResult.

I'm just interested in getting the byte[] from the file.

I've tried:

```
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(Document.Url);
            bytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
        }
```

**This works but I get a corrupted file as expected.**

I do not have control over how the server generates or serves the file.

Any way to wait for the file to complete generating and then get the file content?

TIA

Comment: quick note to say you should use `HttpClient` not `WebClient`
also there are loads of similar questions on here with good answers, so have a look at those first

Comment: Thanks Llama. Non of those worked because of what the server returns. I've explained in my answer below. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Turns out the link returns some javascript that auto authenticates a user and then does a jquery get to another url and port to generate the file. So I was basically downloading that script and saving it to pdf. doh.

So a work around would be to mimic that in some way.